# How to call second exported function from first exported on same js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
import * as endPointUrl from "EndPointUrls";
import axios from "axios";
```

**First function : I just want ot call second function "loginAction()" from inside of first**

```
export const verifyLoginAction = (loginCredential) => (dispatch) => {
    const URL = endPointUrl.VERIFY_EMAI
    axios
        .get(URL)
        .then((res) => {
            loginAction(loginCredential)

        });
};
```

Second Function:

```
export const loginAction = (loginCredential) => (dispatch) => {
    const URL = endPointUrl.LOGIN;
    axios
        .get(URL)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
        });
};
```

** I have attached Screen shot for each component**

[This is my component, I am calling action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqoqW.png)

[This is my action page, from component, I am calling "verifyLoginAction" and again on success of "verifyLoginAction" i am calling next function of same action page "loginAction"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3paEq.png)

[on console view, i can see only log for "verifyLoginAction", call is not going for next function "loginAction"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgMYP.png)

Comment: This should be perfectly fine-- exported functions are still declared in the namespace of the module, and should have direct access to one another.  The catch here, I'm guessing is that you reference `loginAction` before it has actually been declared.  Are you trying this and running into a problem?  If so, what is the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: @AlexanderNied:Thanks for quick reply. Actually, Call is not going to for second function

Comment: well, I am trying to access function ```LoginAction`` declare it before calling function .But Things are still same

Comment: Could you include the behavior you are seeing? What happens when you try?  Do you get an error?  Nothing happens?  How is it invoked?  There's just a bit too little context to provide you with more feedback.

Comment: @AlexanderNied, I have attached all the screen shot of code, console, component. 
I hope, now it is more clear to understand

Comment: So I think I understand what is happening now-- see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I believe you are conflating a few things here.  It appears that `loginAction` and `verifyLoginAction` are both being defined as thunks, in that they are not called directly but in a manner that returns a function that then accepts a dispatch-- usually this pattern is used in something like [react-redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk).  So calling `loginAction` to actually execute the inner-function would require `loginAction(loginCredential)(/*dispatch!?*/)`.  That second function call is *supposed* to be passed `dispatch`, which would usually get stitched together in whatever library was being used.  I suppose here it isn't *critical* as `dispatch` appears to never be used in the inner function; however, I am concerned that you are mixing patterns and bypassing your intended logic flow in a way that could yield unintended consequences down the road.

Comment: Thanks for writing suggestion, it is working. You save my day. thanks again man.

you are saying "mixing patterns and bypassing your intended logic flow". Thanks for letting me know a way to improve 

as I am new to react. can you help me to know, How can i handle this in a correct way, :)

Comment: No problem!  The "correct way" depends-- presumably your functions are setup in this manner because you are leveraging a state machine like react-redux.  Is this the case?  Or are you not actually using anything like that?

Comment: Yes, I am using react-redux

Comment: So, I'm pretty sure this thunk pattern in React/Redux apps is most generally used in the [react-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware.  If you are using this, I'd take a look at the readme page and pay careful attention to the "composition" section.  If you are _not_ using it, then perhaps you've simply made a mistake or misunderstood some example, and you can restructure your actions as simple functions.